# Invoke KeyDown on WPF Control?

Tags: wpf, keypress, keydown

I have two entirely uncoupled WPF windows, however, if something particular is happening in window 1, I do want to invoke or 'simulate' a Key.Up/.Down on a control on the 2nd window. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are they sharing an application? If they do, you should be able to call `BeginInvoke` on the control's event handler

But why to simulate a key press when you can just call a function?

Comment: The windows are within the same application. Basically the usecase is that in certain scenarios the KeyUp/KeyDown events shall be 'forwarded' to a control on the second window and not be performed on the main one... and not call a method per se.

Comment: Then in these scenarios just call the event handler for the other control with the same params; or better yet - have them both use the same event handler, in which you'll decide what to do based on your scenario